# Page reloading problems ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static

I hope you're doing well.

Actually I've the home page that show the same information even if change the code or the css style .

For example :

1- the page has a navigation bar whith the following links : `"home"`, `"blog"`, `"contact"`

2- I add a link named  `"our company"`,

3- when I refresh the page I don't see `"our company"`, but only, `"home"`, `"blog"`, `"contact"`, nothing change

I must confess that I was experimenting caching...

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for helping

Comment: More details are needed; perhaps controller / view code, perhaps log messages.. it's hard to say what's wrong with this little information.

Comment: sorry if I've not been clear.I've tweaked the question.Hope it will be  more clear

Comment: What kind of caching are you doing?  Rails page, fragment or action caching?  Varnish caching?

Comment: I was doing page caching on the home page with the following code `caches_page :index`

Comment: What is the value of config.cache_classes in the environment.rb file ?

Comment: I've `config.cache_classes = false` by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution that is not the most efficient to find the real solution to the problem.

I finally reset the project to the last git revision.I've lost some hours of work but I can't waist my time trying to fix it.

Thanks all of you for helping!!

Answer (score 1):

If you stop your web server and restart it (or, if you're on a service like Heroku, just restart it) you should see the new link appear. Make sure you've saved the change, that you've committed it to your git (or subversion) repository, and deployed your latest code to your server.

Comment: Hooo! I have to precise that I'm on development environment.Even if I restart the server the link doesn't appear like it's supposed to.